# Why are Play actions single threaded?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Given the following Play action:

```
Action {
  Future { println("PLOP") }
  Thread.sleep(2000)
  Ok("")
}
```

I noticed that, using Play's default execution context (ec), "PLOP" is printed out after the sleep. Using `ExecutionContext.global` however, "PLOP" is printed before the sleep as expected.
Therefore I conclude that either Play's default ec is somehow configured to give exactly one thread to each action, or that I somehow manage to exhaust the thread pool (which is unlikely given there was no other actions running at the same time).

Any idea?

Notes:

- Using Play 2.8.8
- No akka configuration whatsoever in my .conf files

Comment: Can you expand a bit more what code you wrote to test the `ExecutionContext`?

Comment: Are you running in dev mode? Because dev mode is single threaded.

Comment: @GaëlJ I tested with the code I wrote in the question.

Comment: @MichaelZajac Yes I run in dev mode. Can you point me to the doc or code to support your answer?